# How does variable-size lookaround work

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

How RegEx engines works internally when they reach to more than one look-around part in a RegEx.

I already  read this [excellent article](http://perl.plover.com/Regex/article.html) but it do not cover lookaround. Can anybody please explain lookarounds (negative,positive,behind,forward) mechanism in general in a similar method?

(also I am interested to know how following regex are interpreted by engine: (`RegEx`s are distinct regex strings and may be variable-size i.e. include `+` or `*`)

```
RegEx (?<!RegEx)(?<=RegEx)(?!RegEx)(?=RegEX) RegEx (?<!RegEx)(?<=RegEx)(?!RegEx)(?=RegEx)  RegEx
```

, I do not want to know what will be matched with them but I want know how engine behave with them, they are just example. Thanks

**A NFA (Non-deterministic Finite Automation) diagram or any similar diagram is very useful to illustrate the topic.**

Please do not refer me to regular-expressions.info, I already read that! It just used two very simple example, I want to know engine mechanism in general.

Comment: The backref section of the paper is a good start. Note that NFAs cannot do this stuff; the various nonregular extensions basically require a DFA engine. The debug prints suggested in the paper (`perl -Dr -ne 'm/regex/' </dev/null`) should also be worth examining for the expressions you want to understand. I'm not sure if there are tutorials about this but you should be able to cope; this basically dumps a bunch of opcodes.

Answer (score 1):

Lookahead is simple: when the engine encounters a lookahead expression, it will save the current position and normally check if it matches. If not, it returns failure (allowing the engine to check other options for earlier parts of the regex). If it does, it restores the saved position and continues checking the rest of the regex.

Lookbehind is tougher. In Python, there is a restriction on them that they must be fixed size. This makes evaluation easy: when it is encountered, the previous [width] characters are checked if they match the expression, and the rest works like lookahead. If you don't use this fixed-size restriction, the evaluation becomes much slower. That doesn't mean the algorithm becomes complex: it can simply try for all strings before the current position (the 0 characters before it, the 1 character before it, the 2 characters before it, etc, until there is a match, or the beginning of the string is reached).

As for the order, a regex is greedy by default. This means that in an expression like `.*(s?)`, the `(s?)` never matches anything, because if there was an s, it is already matched by the `.*`. If you don't want this, add a `?` after the `*` or `+`.

Now to your examples:

- `/.*a(?=.*)/` matches anything up to and including the last `a` (it's greedy). `(?=.*)` always matches, so it is worthless: the regex is identical if it is omitted.
- `/.*a(?!a*)/` never matches anything: the expression in the negative lookahead always matches (if only as "0 times `a`"). Since it's negative, this means the lookahead always fails.
- `/.*a(?=[^a]*)(?=[x])(?![c]*)/` never matches anything. The engine will first try `.*a` to match evertything up to and including the last `a`. This is never followed by another `a`, so the first lookahead always succeeds (the first time only). The next lookahead will fail if there is no `x` after it (note the the brackets are not useful there; `[x]` is identical to `x`). If it fails, it will try a shorter string for `.*a`, until the (first and) second lookahead do match. Note that the first lookahead always matches if the second does, so it isn't useful. The third lookahead ruins it all, though: `[c]*` (which is identical to `c*`) always matches (in any location you can say "this empty string is a list of 0 times the character c"), which means the negative lookahead always fails.

What you may find interesting, is what happens if patterns are made non-greedy. For example, `/.*?a/` will match anything containing an `a`, up to and including the first (as opposed to the last) `a` in the string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The examples was not important by itself, my concern was a general form, a diagram or flowchart of engine cam show general behavior, the question is updated.

Comment: My intention was to explain how the engine works by analyzing your examples. The implementation details may differ per engine (and therefore no general flow chart is possible), but this is the general idea. While this is not a graphical explanation as you request, I tried to give all the information. What information are you still missing?